# Does SPI Configuration Persist After DRV8873 Power-Off?

Tags: microcontroller, power-engineering

I am designing board to drive BDC motors using a DRV8908-Q1.

Here is the data sheet.
[DataSheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/drv8873.pdf?ts=1695021348032)

I would like to inquire if SPI config persists (not go back to DEFAULT) after the driver is powered-off.

Answer (score 0):

The DRV8908 has only volatile registers, after power up all config data is lost.
The register maps show you for all registers the default value that is loaded into the register at power on.

To store the data persistently would require some sort of flash or EEPROM. If the front-page of the datasheet doesn't boast with such a non-volatile memory chances are already pretty high that the chip does not contain persistant storage.